# Installing elfutils-libelf, failed dependency that's already installed?

Tags: centos, rpm

I, stupidly, uninstalled Python (I was having trouble with it for something else I needed) and didn't realise Yum needed it. So when I tried installing Python with a Yum command of course it didn't work.

I've managed to reinstall Python, and am now trying to get Yum working again but to install the Yum RPM I need some other dependencies installed, however one RPM needed is elfutils-libelf

I'm trying to install elfutils-libelf using the following command:

> rpm -Uvh
> http://mirror.centos.org/centos/4/os/i386/CentOS/RPMS/elfutils-libelf-0.97.1-5.i386.rpm

When I run that command I get the following output:

> error: Failed dependencies:
> elfutils-libelf = 0.97-5 is needed by (installed) elfutils-0.97-5.i386

Seeing as that's the RPM I'm trying to install, it doesn't make an awful lot of sense, to me.

I ran the following command and got the following output:

> rpm -qa | grep elfutils-libelf
>
> elfutils-libelf-0.97-5

So it looks installed.... I've tried uninstalling it to reinstall it but there's other dependencies preventing me from doing that.

My knowledge on Linux is very limited, so forgive me.

**EDIT-**

I ran the following command:

> wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/4/os/i386/CentOS/RPMS/elfutils-libelf-0.97.1-5.i386.rpm
> rpm -i elfutils-libelf-0.97.1-5.i386.rpm

And got the following output:

> file /usr/lib/libelf.so.1 from install of elfutils-libelf-0.97.1-5 conflicts with file from package elfutils-libelf-0.97-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it seems weird...

Can you boot in rescue mode from the installtion CD ?

If yes, you could use the yum command from the rescue system to reinstall yum on the system...

Yum should have the "installroot" option available so...

Should I try to remember how to do it ?

Comment: I'm not sure where my disc is at the moment, so I'll go digging for it. I'll see what I can do when I put the disc in, I'll see what options come up :) Thanks

Comment: Turns out the installation CD was a Mistero - Web Server disc. It has things like BlueQuartz and Webmin on it. I can't boot with this to boot into a rescue mode.

Comment: I copied the rpm's from the disc to my computer, then FTP'd them onto the server, and reinstalled ... Turns out it was still a Python problem. I think I had the wrong version or something.
Just some minor yum issues to fix now. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade `elfutils` instead:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/4/os/i386/CentOS/RPMS/elfutils-0.97.1-5.i386.rpm
```

Comment: When I run that command I get the same error as before:

Comment: error: Failed dependencies:
        elfutils-libelf = 0.97.1-5 is needed by elfutils-0.97.1-5.i386